# Need help with a torus animation

Tags: geometry, animation

> Make a movie that shows creation of the torus in yet another manner. Namely, imagine a thin inflatable wire that runs inside the torus along the circle
> $\qquad (x^2) + y^2 = (a^2), \quad z=0$

I was given the following as one way of animating a torus drawing.

```
torus[a_, b_, umin_, umax_, vmin_, vmax_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[{(a + b Cos[u])*Cos[v], (a + b Cos[u])*Sin[v], b*Sin[u]}, 
    {u, umin, umax}, {v, vmin, vmax}, 
    PlotPoints -> 30]

creation2[FromU_, ToU_]:=
  Animate[
    Show[torus[2, 1, FromU, U, 0, 2*Pi],
    PlotRange->{{-3.5 , 3.5}, {-3.5, 3.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], {U, FromU + 0.01, ToU},
    AnimationRunning -> False];
```

I need another way, such as the 1st paragraph suggests by starting with a thin wire, then inflating it into a torus, and also a way of doing the inverse.

Comment: OK Cool problem. What have you tried?

Comment: Ive tried switching u and v

Comment: You haven't defined `torus`.  Please advise.

Comment: torus[a_, b_, umin_, umax_, vmin_, vmax_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{(a + b*Cos[u])*Cos[v], (a + b*Cos[u])*Sin[v], 
   b*Sin[u]}, {u, umin, umax}, {v, vmin, vmax}, PlotPoints -> 30]

Comment: Is this a homework problem or something...?

Comment: Just gonna put this out there, but you should really be able to play around with the definition of `torus` that you gave us and adjust the parameters there to do this. I'll give you a hint: `a` controls the radius of the circle the torus wraps around and `b` in the definitions controls the radius of the disc that is revolved around that circle.

Comment: Thanks for the `torus` definition, but now we need you define `bCos[ ]`.  `b*Cos[ ]` Please clarify/advise.

Comment: I meant to ask whether you meant: `b*Cos[ ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Animate[Show[torus[2, j, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0, 2 \[Pi]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.5, 3.5}, {-3.5, 3.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], {j, 0, 1}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

If I understood you correctly.